# Adding Magnetic Fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Ok, so we all know that the strength of a magnetic field can be increased if a wire with current flowing through it is surrounding the magnet. Because the current flowing through the wire is making a small magnetic field. And supposedly the magnetic field of the magnet adds to the magnetic field of the wire, but I have several questions about this:

1. Why can magnetic fields be added?
2. How do they add together (at a very microscopic scale)?
3. Is there any formula to calculate by how much the strength of the magnetic field increases?

Comment: Magnetic fields add like vectors... not sure I understand your question. Because you presumably already know that and really are asking something else. But what?

Comment: As the question stands, it is very confusing what you're asking

Comment: Are you asking for the equation giving the magnetic field in a solenoid?

Comment: Did this question appear out if nowhere in science or poetry class? Your first sentence sounds like gothic revival writing, the last two points have the structure of a Haiku gone awfully wrong.

Comment: Magnetic fields add in accordance to superposition principle (which is an experimental fact). If that's what you are asking. They don't have to add at the microscopic scale.

Comment: He's asking how the fields of an electromagnet with the core being a magnet merge. I doubt whether it is a simple addition due to things like saturation.